# Does windows 10 always request for dynamic dns update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I have:
A Windows 2016 Server with DHCP and DNS server with "Dynamically update DNS records only if requested by the DHCP clients" checked.
I am not using AD.
Will a Windows 10 client always request for a dynamic dns update by the DHCP server or where can that be configured?

Answer (score 1):

A DNS entry is usually cached for only some time, which is communicated to
the local client by the DNS server.

This is called [Time to live (TTL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live):

> Time to live (TTL) or hop limit is a mechanism that limits the lifespan or lifetime of data in a computer or network. TTL may be implemented as a counter or timestamp attached to or embedded in the data. Once the prescribed event count or timespan has elapsed, data is discarded or revalidated. In computer networking, TTL prevents a data packet from circulating indefinitely. In computing applications, TTL is commonly used to improve the performance and manage the caching of data.

Although some programs have their own internal DNS cache and may ignore the TTL
(Chrome is one example), the DNS Client service of Windows will honor it.

TTL is the main reason that DNS changes may take hours to propagate throughout
the entire Web.

Answer (score -1):

windows dynamic DNS is not dependent on AD.  it queries the domain suffix of the host for the SOA and then picked the first DNS server to submit the DDNS.